# Missing data when performing rolling join

Tags: join

I've got two data sets, one consisting of merger data (e.g., merger dates, price paid, etc.) and another consisting of company level financial statement data (e.g., assets, cash flow, etc.).  I want to join the two data sets by a unique CUSIP number associated with the targets of the mergers and then by the most recent financial statement data prior to the merger.

Example:

```
DS1(Target_CUSIP=c(123456, 234567, 345678, 123456), merger_signing_date=c(12/30/2015, 05/08/2008, 06/02/2013), price=c(1.5, .78, 2, .4))
DS2(Target_CUSIP=c(123456, 123456, 123456, 234567, 234567, 234567, 345678, 345678, 345678), financial_statement_date(10/31/12, 10/31/13, 10/31/15, 12/31/06, 12/31/07, 12/31/08, 12/31/2011, 12/31/2012, 12/31/2013))
```

Here's what I input:

```
setkey(DS2, Target_CUSIP, financial_statement_date)
setkey(DS1, Target_CUSIP, merger_signing_date)
DS2[DS1, roll=T]
```

This ends up matching all of the observations from DS1 to the corresponding data from DS2 but some of the DS2 data ends up missing after the join even though that same data is definitely present in DS2 prior to the join.

Thanks for any help you might offer.

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that the syntax is correct.  There must be an error in the underlying data, particularly the formatting of the CUSIPs.